# How does transaction propagation modes(supports, requires_new etc) affect database connection pool?

Tags: database, spring, connection, spring-transactions

I have a spring boot app, configured with max 100 db connections.

**CODE 1.**

```
public class Class1
  {
    @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void service1(){
      new Class2().service2();
    }
  }
  public class Class2
  {
    @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void service2(){..}
  }
```

**CODE 2.**

```
public class Class1
  {
    @Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void service1(){
      new Class2().service2();
    }
  }
  public class Class2
  {
    @Transactional(propagation=SUPPORTS)
    public void service2(){..}
  }
```

Question. If only one call is made to service1, how many db connections are used in both the cases. Does CODE1 use 2 db connections to carry out the service2 transaction, or does it reuse the existing db connection that was available to service1?

Comment: In Code 1, as the propagation is REQUIRES_NEW for both the classes, which means that once the call is handled to the service2 method, it comes to the second transaction context, so it suspends the current transaction and a new one is created.

In Code 2, as the propagation is SUPPORTS when the code enters the second method service2, still it continues the same transaction as its propagation mode is SUPPORTS.

So in Code1 has  two connections are made and code 2 one connection is made.